# c++ fopen is returning a file * with <bad ptr>'s

Tags: c++, libjpeg

I copied this code from the libjpeg example and im passing it standard files;

```
FILE *soureFile;
if ((soureFile = fopen(sourceFilename, "rb")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", sourceFilename);
    exit(1);
}

jpeg_stdio_src(&jpegDecompress, soureFile);
jpeg_read_header(&jpegDecompress, true);
```

It results in a file pointer that contains no information and therefore breaks on the last line with access violations.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:** On Tobias' advice the fopen does appear to open the file ok but the jpeg_read_header is in turn failing with the access violation still.

**EDIT:** After a little more digging
[JPEG support with ijg - getting access violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391917/jpeg-support-with-ijg-getting-access-violation)

Comment: Are you sure that the rest of the code isn't at fault, and that the file contains what you think it does?

Comment: I am still not clear. Is fopen() the above code returning NULL or not?

Comment: if sourceFile != NULL, then fopen succeded. Could you try to read from sourceFile to rule the fopen-part out (for example using fgetc).

Comment: @Neil: fopen returns a file *, whose properties are <bad ptr>'s. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Tobias: i'll try that and eliminate the fopen.

Comment: @Adam a FILE * is an opague pointer - you are not supposed to do anything with it except use it with the various stream APIs. You certainly can't extract useful inforrmation from it.

Comment: @Adam: Can you tell whether jpeg_stdio_src() call succeeds? Also whether you are reading the file inside it?

Comment: how is jpedDecompress declared and allocated? I guess you have a memory violation with the jpegDecompress-Pointer being written at.

Comment: The programmer is not really supposed to make use of the individual fields of a FILE struct. The fact that it contains bad pointers does not necessarily mean that the structure is corrupted, but rather that those fields are not meant to be used - or used as pointers - at the time you read it.

Comment: @Naveen: It appears as though it is successful, there is no return code, and the built in error mechanism (for libjpeg) is reporting no error.
@RaphaelSP: thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Tobias: it is declared as an automatic variable, as per the example. And then initialised via jpeg_create_decompress

Comment: what compiler is used for the dll and for your code? Perhaps using the same compiler solves your problem with the FILE-pointer being transferred to the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[`select` isn't broken](http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)".

If `fopen` returned a valid file pointer, and `jpeg_read_header` can't use it, someone between those two statements has done something bad to it.

The only one in between is the `jpg_stdio_src` call, which wouldn't fail if all it's preconditions are fulfilled.

Bottom line: see why `jpg_stdio_src` fails.  My guess: it needs to be constructed using the [`jpeg_create_decompress`](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libjpeg-ddefs.html) macro.

Answer (score 2):

Use strerror or perror to get exact reason:

```
FILE *soureFile;
if ((soureFile = fopen(sourceFilename, "rb")) == NULL)
{
    perror("fopen failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about those thanks.
However due to the valid pointer being return from fopen, this line will never be hit.

Comment: So in fact fopen() is working and the problem is with your jpeg code!

Comment: I think what Adam means is that the pointer `fopen` returns is valid and points to a valid `struct` but the data in the `struct` is invalid. I just ran into this problem and hence this question. To further clarify, the debugger can access the variables in the returned value: `_ptr`, `_base` and `_tmpfname` are all invalid pointers. What we are told when looking at `fopen`'s documentation is that if the file fails to open, `NULL` will be returned. This is not the case here.